# How to exclude certain branches for a path pattern within Github Actions?

Tags: github, path, github-actions, git-filter-branch, git-filter

How to apply `branches-ignore` and `paths-ignore` on GitHub Actions? For example, if I have the following source tree:

```
|-src\
|----reports\
|-------<foo>DailyReports.ts
```

I want to only deploy that to production (`master` branch) but NOT staging (`staging` branch).
Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to achieve what you want with `ON` trigger configuration alone. Therefore **the implementation below wouldn't work** as it would trigger for push to the specified path `OR` for push to the master branch, but not only for both:

```yaml
on:
 push:
   path: 
     - 'src/reports/*DailyReports.ts'
   branches:
     - master
```

In that case, you could do it by using only one trigger at the workflow level, and check the other condition with an `IF` expression.

**For example by doing this:**

```yaml
on:
 push:
   path: 
     - 'src/reports/*DailyReports.ts'

jobs:
  job1:
  runs-on: ...
  if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' # run this job only for the master branch
  steps:
   ...
```

Or by checking the branch at the workflow level, and then use something like this [path-filter action](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter) to check if the file or directory has been updated or not before performing some operation.

*I personally suggest the first option (*cf example*), as it's less verbose.*

Note: If the `src/reports/*DailyReports.ts` path isn't working as expected, you can use the [filter pattern cheat sheet](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet) to find the right expression.

Comment: I am sure whether your statement regarding the OR behavior of the first example is true. According to the Github [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore), if both `branches` and `paths` are defined, then the workflow will only run if **both** conditions are met.